# How to properly change setState in my situation

Tags: reactjs

I am making a very simple "like" app, you got a few pictures, each of them have a button underneath and when you click the like button, it increases by 1, currently everything is hardcoded.

I have 3 of the same component written in my main file

```
 <Test number="5" key="0" get={this.testing} > (this 3 times with a picture Img between them)



state = {
   data: [
      {counter: 0, Alt: "Pengo"},
      {counter: 0, Alt: "Zebra"},
      {counter: 0, Alt: "Kuma"},
      ]
  }
```

How do I make the function, which will take Test's number property(those 3 Test's will have 3 different numbers) and setState it by 1? (aka, that counter up in the state will increase by 1 depending on which Test's like button I press. If I press the like button on the Test with number 3, it will find the counter of that Test and increase it by 1)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass back the number/index of the task that was clicked and then update the state in Parent.

Parent:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      { counter: 0, Alt: "Pengo" },
      { counter: 0, Alt: "Zebra" },
      { counter: 0, Alt: "Kuma" },
    ]
  }
  testing = (number) => {
    const no = Number(number);
    const data = [...this.state.data];
    data[no].counter++;
    this.setState({data});
  }
  render() {
    return (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Test number="0" key="0" get={this.testing} data={this.state.data} />
    <Test number="1" key="1" get={this.testing} data={this.state.data} />
    <Test number="2" key="2" get={this.testing} data={this.state.data} />
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
  </div>
);
  }
}
```

Task:

```
export default class Tasks extends React.Component {

  increment = () => {
    this.props.get(this.props.number);
  }
  render() {
    const { number, data } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{data[Number(number)].counter}</div>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**[Sample working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/049lxjoyrv)**